# Ansible - filter stdout_lines

Tags: ansible

I want to parse from debug VARNAME.stdout_lines to show me only specific lines. Is it possible without using bash?

I have the following example of the debug variable on stdout_lines:

`hostname1`

```
"statusapplication.stdout_lines": [
    "httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server",
    " Loaded: Loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)",
    " Active: active ....",
    "  Docs: man:httpd(8)",
    " Process: .....",
]
```

Is there any possibility to extract only first 3 lines from this? I mead the Service name, Loaded and Active?

I tried something like to extract only the Active:

```
- name: parse stdout_lines   
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.Active }}"
  with_items: "{{ statusapplication.Active }}"
```

Comment: What is `statusapplication.Active`? I thought you were trying to use `statusapplication.stdout_lines`?

Comment: yep, I'm using statusapplication.stdout_lines but that output contains multiple lines and I want to select only a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list and you only want the first three items in the list, you can use list slicing to get that.  For example the following playbook:

```
---
- gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    statusapplication:
      stdout_lines: [
        "httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server",
        " Loaded: Loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)",
        " Active: active ....",
        "  Docs: man:httpd(8)",
        " Process: .....",
    ]

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ statusapplication.stdout_lines[:3] }}"
```

Will output:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server) => {
    "msg": "httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item= Loaded: Loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)) => {
    "msg": " Loaded: Loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item= Active: active ....) => {
    "msg": " Active: active ...."
}
```

If your goal is actually to extract information from those lines, you might instead use `set_fact` to create a series of variables, and reference each line explicitly by index:

```
---
- gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    statusapplication:
      stdout_lines: [
        "httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server",
        " Loaded: Loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)",
        " Active: active ....",
        "  Docs: man:httpd(8)",
        " Process: .....",
    ]

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        service_name: "{{ statusapplication.stdout_lines[0] }}"
        service_loaded: "{{ statusapplication.stdout_lines[1].split()[1] }}"
        service_status: "{{ statusapplication.stdout_lines[2].split()[1] }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Service '{{ service_name }}' is {{ service_loaded }} and {{ service_status }}."
```

Which outputs:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Service 'httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server' is Loaded and active."
}
```

But for what you're trying to do, you may instead want to investigate Ansible's [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html) module, which will return information about running services in a structured format.

For example:

```
---
- gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - service_facts:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ services['sshd.service'] }}"
```

Which produces:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "sshd.service",
        "source": "systemd",
        "state": "running",
        "status": "enabled"
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only work when the user that playbook is running in target host has priviledged access otherwise it hangs. Also in my case the user only had access to some of the services as admiistrator but not all and it hangs the playbook. so service_stats isn't helpful.